# Select certain button values on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On a view/edits section of a bookings page, i have a table generated through AJAX with a booking time, Room no, Date, and a Edit booking that has a Button with a value assigned to it that starts from 0 and goes up depending on how many rows are generated so when clicked, i can target that row by the value number to grab the correct fields to send to my SQL statement.

```
<? php 
function usersBookings($group) {
        $q = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `timeslot`.`shortDesc`, `booking`.`room_ID`, `booking`.`date` FROM `booking` JOIN `timeslot` ON `timeslot`.`blockID` = `booking`.`block_ID` 
        WHERE `team_name` LIKE ? ORDER BY `booking`.`date` ASC");
        $q->execute(Array($group));
        $str =  "<table id='userTable' style='width:80%'>
                    <tr>
                        <th style='border-bottom:1px solid black'>Booking Time</th>
                        <th style='border-bottom:1px solid black'>Room Number</th>
                        <th style='border-bottom:1px solid black'>Date</th>
                        <th style='border-bottom:1px solid black'>Edit Booking</th>
                    </tr>";
            $counter = 0;
            while ($result = $q->fetch()) {
                    $str .= "<tr>
                        <td>$result[0]</td>
                        <td>$result[1]</td>
                        <td>$result[2]</td>
                        <td><button class='edit_btn' value='$counter'>Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>";

                $counter++;         
            }

            $str .= "</table>";
            return $str;
    }
?>
```

Now i'm trying to target which button is clicked through jQuery to target that specific row:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $buttonNo = $('#userTable button').val(); // Not sure how to target.

 $field1 = $('#userTable tr:nth-child(' + $buttonNo + ') td:nth-child(1)');
 $field2 = $('#userTable tr:nth-child(' + $buttonNo + ') td:nth-child(2)');
 $field3 = $('#userTable tr:nth-child(' + $buttonNo + ') td:nth-child(3)');
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to target the correct clicked button though.

Please forgive the code, completely new to PHP and jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `.click` event and get `this`:

```
$('#userTable button').click(function(){
     $buttonNo = $(this).val(); 
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate('#userTable button', 'click', function() {
    $buttonNo = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.